# what does -r argument in php -r mean?

Tags: php

I googled but didn't find any relevant content for `PHP -r`.
I used php -r for fetching environment variable in my code.

```
php -r 'print getenv("FOO");'
```

What does -r do, and how can I find all `arguments` which can be used with php.

Comment: did you try to read https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: or more specifically https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: Run `man php`. This goes for virtually every single linux program ever.

Answer (score 1):

When running command line php, the `-r` flag allows you to run code without any script tags ( `<?php` and `?>` )